# growable wxpython listctrl columns

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to create a table, using a wxlistctrl, where the columns will grow along with it's parent.  I want it to function like a gridbagsizer with growable columns.  I also don't want the user to be able to adjust the width by clicking and dragging the vertical rules.  Is this possible with the listctrl or am i going to have to make my own control?

Here is an example of what I have now

```
import wx
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Tutorial")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0
        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(-1,100),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                         )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Subject')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Due')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Location', width=125)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Line")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_line)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def add_line(self, event):
        line = "Line %s" % self.index
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, "01/19/2010")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, "USA")
        self.index += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Can we see your code please? :)

Comment: I'm not sure why code is needed.  Its just a default listctrl right now.

Comment: No one is going to build it *for* you. You should post something you try, or else no one will probably feel the need to help you.

Comment: I am hoping that the answer is a simple flag or function, not a complete overhaul.

Comment: *Life is not always simple* ;)

Answer (score 1):

See the ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin class in the wx.lib.mixins.listctrl module.

Comment: Sorry this has nothing to do with the question - add it as a comment please - he is trying to Veto resizes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can try this;

```
sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 1, wx.ALL | wx.GROW, 5)
```

[image: Demo]

Sadly you can't disable column-width resizing. At least not in the default library; http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ListCtrl.html.

Comment: Sadly you can't disable column-width resizing. --> not true

Answer (score 0):

> I also don't want the user to be able to adjust the width by clicking and dragging the vertical rules.

This at least is possible:

```
    self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_COL_BEGIN_DRAG, self.OnColumnResizeStart)
# ...
def OnColumnResizeStart(self, event):
    # Veto if on auto mode:
    if self.autoColWidths: event.Veto()
    else: event.Skip()
```